Improving efficiency of regexp string detection for large R character vectors
I'm working on a problem in R that requires detecting a bunch of different "patterns" (regular expressions) from an even large bunch of strings. The desired output is a matrix where the # of rows is equal to the # of strings and the # of columns is equal to the # of patterns. I realize that this sort of operation isn't going to run super quickly no matter what, but I am still feeling like I want to speed it up more. As far as I know there are three primary functions used to detect patterns from strings: base::grepl, stringr::str_detect, and stringi::stri_detect_regex. These three functions are all vectorized but only for one dimension at a time; you can give it a vector of strings or a vector of patterns but if you give it both, it won't give you the matrix-style result I imagine. I'm wondering if there's something I haven't thought of that might be a faster alternative to what I want. I have looked through a few other questions about this but couldn't find anything to address this particular issue for really large datasets. I attach a minimal working example of what my desired output looks like (with a much smaller sample):
require(bench)
require(stringr)
require(stringi)

# Fairly large vector of strings
all_strings = stringr::words
# Smaller, but still not tiny, vector of regular expressions to check for each letter, case insensitive
all_patterns = paste0("(?i)", LETTERS)

# All 3 of these lines produce a matrix of logical values indicating whether the (column) pattern is contained within the (row) string
benchmark_all = mark(stringr = {sapply(all_patterns, str_detect, string = all_strings)},
                     stringi = {sapply(all_patterns, stri_detect_regex, str = all_strings)},
                     grepl = {sapply(all_patterns, grepl, x = all_strings)})

And here is the output of said benchmark on my computer, which basically says that stringi is a little bit faster than stringr, which is in turn a lot faster than grepl.
> benchmark_all
# A tibble: 3 × 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result   memory     time      
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>   <list>     <list>    
1 stringr      3.53ms   3.84ms      229.     307KB        0   118     0      515ms <lgl[…]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
2 stringi      2.79ms   3.27ms      250.     300KB        0   125     0      501ms <lgl[…]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
3 grepl        4.15ms    6.8ms      155.     300KB        0    78     0      503ms <lgl[…]> <Rprofmem> <bench_tm>
# ℹ 1 more variable: gc <list>

I am running this on Windows 11 x64 with R 4.3.3. Any feedback is welcome; thanks!

Just side notes. There might be a way to use fixed=TRUE in grepl. vapply is safer and faster than sapply. For the given example we would need FUN.VALUE = logical(length(all_strings)).

Probably not quite what you're after, but for single-character patterns, match is quite fast:
f0 <- function() {
  all_patterns <- paste0("(?i)", LETTERS)
  sapply(all_patterns, str_detect, string = all_strings)
}

f1 <- function() {
  all_patterns <- paste0("(?i)", LETTERS)
  vapply(all_patterns, str_detect, string = all_strings,
         logical(length(all_strings)))
}

f2 <- function() {
  m <- matrix(FALSE, length(all_strings), 26)
  m[(match(unlist(strsplit(all_strings, "")), c(letters, LETTERS)) - 1L)%%26L*
      length(all_strings) + rep.int(1:length(all_strings),
                                    nchar(all_strings))] <- TRUE
  m
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  sapply = f0(),
  vapply = f1(),
  match = f2()
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
#>  sapply 4183.0 4417.75 6154.608 4548.05 4855.05 115796.7   100
#>  vapply 4147.5 4316.20 4779.976 4436.65 4793.05   8363.3   100
#>   match  567.7  637.45  940.737  675.55  720.80  12442.5   100

Check that the results are the same.
identical(f0(), f1())
#> [1] TRUE
identical(unname(f0()), f2())
#> [1] TRUE


f2() is great (+1) but it is on top of the assumption that all_strings consists of LETTERS only.  Could you make it more general and retain its speedy performance?
